# select and replace all non keyboard characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here's my code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `accounts` 
WHERE NOT name REGEXP  '^[[.NUL.]-[.DEL.]]*$'
```

I want all non keyboard characters across all tables to be replaced with a space.

Hoping that someone can actually do this.

Comment: You should clarify the meaning of "non keyboard"?

Comment: non-keyboard means ascii codes that does not have an equivalent key in keyboard. Sample  is CAN which is cancel and EM which is end of medium.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. When I said clarify, I meant more about which keyboard. Do you mean only ascii keyboard plus special characters which are on keyboard, or you mean all printable characters? What about cyrillic keyboards, etc?

Comment: Here's the list of ascii codes that i need to replace with a space bar. Aside.Aside from this anyone should do just fine. I just want this list to be replaced with a space bar.      NUL
SOH
STX
ETX
EOT
ENQ
ACK
BEL
LF
VT
FF
CR
SO
SI
DLE
DC1
DC2
DC3
DC4
NAK
SYN
ETB
CAN
EM
SUB
FS
GS
RS
US

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do this easily in SQL.

The most straightforward approach would be to take a logical backup of your database, use `sed` or `perl` (or some similar tool to do the string replacement), and then re-import the data.

You should test this by importing the data into a test database (or at least a test schema) to make sure it doesn't harm your data.

Assuming by "non keyboard" characters you are referring to "non-printable" characters, and that you are on linux, you can do this with a combination of mysqldump and sed like so:

```
# dump your schema and data
mysqldump --single-transaction your_schema > /tmp/your_schema.sql  

# copy the dump file and replace all non-printable characters with a space
sed -e 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g' /tmp/your_schema.sql > /tmp/your_schema_test.sql

# create an empty test schema to test the import
mysqladmin create your_schema_test

# import the data into the test schema
mysql -f your_schema_test < /tmp/your_schema_test.sql
```